# Back button is not closing APP in Samsung Devices

Tags: android

I'm facing something weird just on Samsung Devices.

If I fully stop the APP from the settings, and then I launch it, it's working properly.
However, if I stop the APP by pressing back button in order to go back to Android Home, (note that method onDestroy is triggered!), when I reopen the APP, the APP doesn't start from scratch, it tries to display the last Activity.

Did you guys face something like that before?

As I said, it's only happening in Samsung Devices...

Comment: Did you override onKeyDown() ? onBackPressed() ?

Comment: no, I did not. The weird thing is that the Activity Flow is correct, as "onDestroy" is triggered. I've forced a `System.exit(0)` on `onDestroy` method, and now it's working, but this is so ugly and I shouldn't do that.

Comment: Override onKeyDown() and onBackPressed() and print log inside and check.

Comment: please post your code and manifest.xml also.

Comment: you want to close app on back button press and next time you start app you wan its start from starting?

Comment: I cannot reproduce that with my own app on a Galaxy S4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like

```
@Override
  public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
      moveTaskToBack(true);
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
  }
```

Comment: I do like this approach and I'm going to keep that. However, I do not like doing specific things just for Samsung devices. I hate samsung at all.

Answer (score 0):

you can override the method onBackPressed() like this

```
@override 
public void onBackPressed()
{
 super.onBackPressed();
 finish();// well totally finish the app
}
```

Comment: `super.onBackPressed()` simply calls `finish()`. Check the [source](https://gitorious.org/rowboat/frameworks-base/source/aa93bcd62482719c146a411008e1eac94135b6a4:core/java/android/app/Activity.java#L1919)

Comment: And it is `finish();` and not `finish()`

Comment: i know the onback well call the finish but this well force it to finish

Comment: As I said in my question, the Activity Flow is followed, as onDestroy method is triggered, however, for some reason APP is not totally removed from memory, which does in other non-samsung devices like Nexus